# Разбор ссылок Google

Tags: google-maps, link

Мне нужно взять широту и долготу с ссылки которую пользователи будут вставлять.
НО, ссылки google бывают разные(длинные, короткие, embed и т.д.).
Как можно реализовать это, если есть какие то идеи и предложения прошу поделиться.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Насколько понятно, вы хотите получить кординаты из ссылки google map ? не легче сделать так чтобы пользователи вставляли не ссылку от google map а просто вставляли определённый адрес ?

Comment: @Arsen Да, нужно получить с ссылок google map, но они бывают разные, мне нужно получать со ВСЕХ видно ссылок google map.

Comment: но бывают ссылки в которых нет кординат, повторюсь,   не легче сделать так чтобы пользователи вставляли не ссылку от google map а просто вставляли определённый адрес ?

Comment: @Arsen Этот способ лёгкий для разработчиков, но не удобен для пользователя моя задача обеспечить максимальную комфортность пользователя.

Comment: лёгкость тут ни причём, или вам придётся заставлять пользователей вводить ссылку в формате google.com/maps/preview/@<latitude>,<longitude>,<zoom level> , или же написать код, который через CURL будет обращатся по введённой ссылке(например по короткой) и парсить полученную информацию, однако google будет  блокировать если будут  много запросов